# Connect one subdomain by HTTPS without SNI

Tags: https, subdomain, sni

I want to use an `https` connexion in a web site. The problem is that the server is handling some subdomains (`http://staging.example.com`, `http://beta.example.com`, `http://www.example.com`), so it seems that I should use [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). But I need just one subdomain to be connected by `https` (`https://beta.example.com`). Is it possible without SNI?

Comment: Are you using any control panel?

Comment: @chility - No. The Linux console.

Comment: I would suggest to install some kind of controll panel. There are few free and good out there. It will make the things 1000 times easier. Just my 2 cents.